# How to prevent child class increase the access privilege of override method?

Tags: android, kotlin

Given this base class with have a protected method `doSomething`. I want all places to call the `invoke` method instead of `doSomething` method because it will have dispatcher

```
abstract class MyParentClass<: O>(val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {

    suspend operator fun invoke(): O{
        return withContext(dispatcher) {
            doSomething()
        }
    }

    // Is the any way to prevent/warning child class to not increase access privilege to public
    protected abstract suspend fun doSomething(): O
}
```

However, in some child class which extends from this class, they can change the access privilege of this method to `public`. Then some places will call the `doSomething` instead of `invoke`.
How do I show some error/warning when calling to `doSomething` or when change the visibility to public?

I tried to mark `doSomething` with `Deprecated` warning, but the method which I override also has warning

Comment: I would consider a message in the docs for the function to be adequate. After all, increasing visibility of something should never be done lightly without consideration. And even if you could make it an error, that would prevent them from calling it from some other public function.

Comment: The only way I see is by providing `doSomething` not as an abstract function, but as a lambda through the constructor. Then it can be private. But I think you shouldn't really care. We can't force subclasses to be implemented correctly. These classes can always invoke `doSomething` or its equivalent code directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you  should worry about that because:

1. If someone creates a new class with an overridden doSomething() method, you will still have your contract where this method is protected
   [image]
2. You can make data which can be exposed as private and don't worry about it

Alternative, I would recommend to use another approach by passing the lambda to you method:

```
abstract class MyParentClass<O>(private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) {

    suspend operator fun invoke(action: suspend () -> O): O {
        return withContext(dispatcher) {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My current issue is we can make doSomething() from protected to public in AnotherClass, so while working in the team, some member may call wrong method.